# Cannot install Servicemix

Tags: apache-servicemix

I am trying to install servicemix, but I cannot get the result that is described in the documentation. 
I have installed JDK, and added to the environmental variables. Then downloaded the serviceMix zip file and ran the command as is described on the pic. But I get stuck on this step...Any hints?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the ServiceMix process is running?

Do a `ps -ef | grep 7.0.1`

It should display a java process running. If not, either you have not started ServiceMix or there is most likely a permissions/ownership issue somewhere.

Otherwise run the `client` executable in the bin folder.

If it still does not work. Kill the ServiceMix process, run the `start` executable and then the `client` executable.